# Finally installed Ubuntu. Did I do something wrong because it's slower than Windows 10?

Tags: firefox

I installed Ubuntu 16.04 on my laptop, a ThinkPad-11e, which has a Celeron N2940 processor and 8gb of RAM. The intentions were to familiarize myself with Linux and eventually hopefully fully transition (or at least mostly transition to Linux-based). I am also learning programming and had the idea that using Linux would be... "better." I'm not sure how or why exactly I had this thought but it seems appropriate.

So I have installed it and it boots up and runs fine every time. However, I haven't used it much. So far all I have gotten around to is some web browsing but Firefox keeps crashing? I get the "unresponsive" script and I just wait a couple seconds and it catches up. This is if I have like a couple tabs open or something. This has already done away with my patience in trying to use it if I can't even lightly browse the web. Did I do something wrong?

My laptop has a 128gb SSD and I partitioned 40gb for Ubuntu. When I was installing, I simply selected the option to "install alongside Windows" and it seemed to automatically take up that unallocated space. But, I did (or thought I did) a good amount of research before installing and I seem to have missed the part where I do the "swap." I never specified any value for swap space. I don't know if this has anything to do with it, but I think Firefox getting held up on just a couple of tabs (no other applications running) can't be right. I thought Ubuntu/Linux in general was supposed to be "lighter" than Windows?

I'm glad I finally installed but I feel like something isn't right. I can't even use it because it's too slow (for browsing the web at least, I really haven't used it for anything else). If anyone can offer some help it would be much appreciated. Thanks

Edit:

```
joe@joe-ThinkPad-11e:~$ sudo lsblk -f
[sudo] password for joe: 
NAME   FSTYPE LABEL     UUID                                 MOUNTPOINT
sda                                                          
├─sda1 vfat   SYSTEM    50D8-647D                            /boot/efi
├─sda2                                                       
├─sda3 ntfs   Windows   AC8CDB4C8CDB1026                     
├─sda4 ntfs   WinRE_DRV 1EC0DB8AC0DB6715                     
├─sda5 ext4             58a1bc8b-7f09-453e-9369-9c323da6669b /
└─sda6 swap             51718413-68c5-4e69-a405-3b1be7a114ff [SWAP]

joe@joe-ThinkPad-11e:~$ sudo lsblk -m
NAME     SIZE OWNER GROUP MODE
sda    119.2G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda1   260M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda2    16M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda3    79G root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda4  1000M root  disk  brw-rw----
├─sda5  31.2G root  disk  brw-rw----
└─sda6   7.9G root  disk  brw-rw----
```

Comment: that processor is affected by the cstate bug [System freezes completely with Intel Bay Trail](//askubuntu.com/a/803649) but idk about slowness

Comment: 1. Please run `sudo lsblk -f` and `sudo lsblk -m` in a terminal window and post the output. 2. Please tell us about your graphics chip/card: brand name and model. It would make it easier to help.

Comment: What's the output of `free -h` (while Firefox is stalling or frozen) and `swapon -s` (at any time)?

Comment: @sudodus: You don't need super-user privileges for `lsblk -m`. :-) I'm also not sure how access permissions are relevant here.

Comment: No not to *run* lsblk, but to make it show as much as possible. The regular user might not have access to everything. I have noticed differences in some cases.

Comment: @sudodus This is my first time EVER dabbling with this stuff. Can you please be more specific with running those in a terminal window.

And the laptop is a Lenovo Thinkpad 11e. The CPU is listed in the post and as for graphics I'm not sure what to tell besides Device Manager > Display Adapters lists Intel(R) HD Graphics

Comment: @DavidFoerster Please be more specific with what I need to do to find those results. I am not sure how to answer your questions.

Keep in mind this is my first time ever using Ubuntu or even Linux

Comment: You start a terminal window with the hotkey combination `ctrl + alt + t`. Then you type those commands into the terminal window and press the Enter key. You will be asked to enter sudo password. Use your normal user password. There will be no feedback. Press the Enter key. Then there should be some lines of output, that you can copy and paste into your question (edit the question), and let us know with a small comment.

Comment: Sure, no problem. Open a terminal (Ctrl+Alt+T) and type in or copy & paste (use a middle mouse click or Ctrl+Shift+V to paste into a terminal) commands into the terminal and press RETURN after each command to run it. You can select terminal content (incl. command output) with the mouse pointer and paste the selected text into a web browser window or text editor with a middle mouse click or with Ctrl+Shift+C (copy selection from terminal) and Ctrl+V (paste into graphical application). You can also use the context menu of either if you prefer. Use the [edit] link below your question to amend it.

Comment: I'd run a WiFi speed test to see if that partly explains Firefox slowness. I'm a fan of Chrome and you have lots of space to install that for side by side comparison. You don't need a swap partition in your environment. Simply close the lid to suspend and don't worry about hibernating.

Comment: I have edited the post @sudodus

Comment: I have edited the post @DavidFoerster

Also, why wasn't I allowed to mention two names in one comment?

Comment: There is swap and it is active, see the lsblk output for `/dev/sda6` :-) But the processor is not very powerful. You could install *htop* and run it in a terminal window to monitor how the processor and memory are used during web browsing: `sudo apt-get install htop` and let us know what you notice. - You will probably get better performance with a lighter flavour of Ubuntu, for example Lubuntu, Xubuntu or Ubuntu MATE. Try them live before installing, https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389

Comment: You can install LXDE (Lubuntu), Xfce (Xubuntu) and MATE without a system reinstallation too and switch between them an Unity as you like. I think your system is powerful enough for Unity. It's roughly the same as mine and I have no performance issues.

Answer (score 0):

There is swap and it is active, see the lsblk output for `/dev/sda6` :-)

But the processor is not very powerful. You could install *htop* and run it in a terminal window to monitor how the processor and memory are used during web browsing:

```
sudo apt-get install htop

htop
```

and let us know what you notice.

You will probably get better performance with a lighter flavour of Ubuntu, for example Lubuntu, Xubuntu or Ubuntu MATE. Ubuntu Gnome might be an alternative to standard Ubuntu if you want good touchscreen behaviour.

And I recommend the version **16.04.1 LTS** with long time support (5 years for standard Ubuntu, 3 years for the community flavours, while 16.10 has only 9 months support). The point releases of the LTS versions are better debugged and polished, look for the **.1** in the file name.

Try them live (booted from an install USB drive, DVD disk or memory card) before installing,

[Try Ubuntu (Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, ...) before installing it](https://ubuntuforums.org/showthread.php?t=2230389)

Comment: Ah okay. So it is due to a weak processor?

Comment: I think it could be, but I am not sure. It is easy to test, *try without installing*, and that way you will find out if it helps with a lighter desktop environment. It could also be a problem because of poor cooperation between the graphics driver and the graphics chip/card, and if you cannot find a better driver, it is a work-around to use a lighter desktop environment.

Comment: Okay I'll try the lighter DEs. But isn't Ubuntu and pretty much all Linux meant to be "lighter" than Windows?

Comment: We cannot say the linux is lighter than Windows in general. Old Windows versions, for example XP, work better in old hardware than some new linux versions. Different linux distros and flavours have different desktop environments. Some focus on a nice user experience, and need a lot of computing power and RAM, others focus on a light foot-print in order to work well in old computers and computers with weak processors and a low amount of RAM. Some graphics cards have no efficient linux driver, so linux has problems, while Windows works well.

Comment: Do you think this has anything to do with it? http://imgur.com/a/nxydX

I haven't installed it yet, but I was wondering what exactly it is and if it is driver software then why wasn't it installed since I'm pretty sure I'm set to auto install updates

Comment: Proprietary software (as opposite to free and open source software) is not installed automatically in linux, but available if you wish to use it. It might or might not improve the performance.

Comment: What would you suggest? What would the common Ubuntu/Linux user recommend?

I just want to know what the common practice is. As of right now I have absolutely no idea why or why I shouldn't use that software. I mean I know why (it could help), but I don't necessarily know why not (besides it being proprietary, which I'm still a little unsure about)

Also, shouldn't there be some owner/writer information? How does this even get published to be found by the OS anyways if it is written by... whoever it is written by?

Comment: I'm confused. I have [these options selected](http://imgur.com/a/DnO0n) but in Ubuntu Software I am still seeing [this](http://imgur.com/a/2fArE).

Comment: To play safe: Backup everything important, or make a full backup of the whole system. After that you dare try 'anything'. If it creates problems, try to undo what you did. If that does not work (for example because the system no longer works), restore it from the backup. - That said, the proprietary code (created by the company, that made the piece of hardware, in this case the graphics chip) is tested by many people and will work well with most models of their hardware, but we cannot guarantee anything.

Comment: The Software Center is a new program, and needs debugging. There is an older tool, The *Synaptic* package manager. It is well debugged and polished, but 'not as user friendly' as what is intended with the Software Center. When you learn how to use Synaptic, you will find that it is a really good tool. I think *Software and Updates* is also working well.